# init() function not run in shared library?

Tags: go, shared-libraries

I'm building my package with `-buildmode=c-shared` and find that the init() functions in imported packages don't seem to be run. Is that intended behavior, a bug, or am I just stupid?
I'm using go1.13.7 on linux/amd64. The function in question looks like this:

```
func init() {
    jsonrpc.HandleFunc("create-context", ContextHandler)
}
```

jsonrpc is a package I wrote and the function adds an entry to an unexported global map there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with:

```
package main

import "C"

import "fmt"

func init() {
        fmt.Println("in init")
}

//export Yo
func Yo() {
        fmt.Println("that's what's up")
}

func main() {
        fmt.Println("vim-go")
}
```

With `go build -buildmode=c-shared lib.go` I got a a `lib.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lol.h"

int main() {
    Yo();
}
```

I compiled with: `gcc -o client main.c ./lib.so`

And I got a:

```
in init
that's what's up
```

So it seems to me that it works.

Comment: Have you tried putting some debug printing in the init() func to see if it was called?

Comment: It really helps when someone asks the right questions! The package wasn't imported anywhere. I got it to work now, thanks!